# Images not store in media folder but creating a folder and store

Tags: django

I am trying to upload some images in my app media folder. The problem is images uploaded successfully but not in media folder. Its creates another folder and store their. My code details are given bellow:

urls.py

```
     from django.contrib import admin
     from django.urls import path
     from ssibdweb import views
     from django.conf import settings
     from django.conf.urls.static import static


    urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('', views.index, name='index'),

      ]
    if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIAFILES_DIRS)
```

settings.py

```
    MEDIA_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIAFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
    ]
```

models.py

```
   class BlogImage(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        sub_id = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/')

        def __str__(self):
           return str(self.id)
```

I am using following form for upload

```
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: But they can't create folder, they only store where you have specified, like in your case it will be store in `blog` folder inside media folder, location will be something like `media/blog`, all images will be uploaded there, and its recommended to follow general rules, which refer in the docs see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/#managing-files), and its `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass **`settings.MEDIAFILES_DIRS`** inside **`static()`** function which is not exists in **`django.conf`** settings you can check available constants of [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/). In order to store your uploaded media content you've to set **`MEDIA_ROOT`** value like this

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

and inside your **urls.py** file change like this

```
 if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```